# Design customizable Size Widget with CSS

Tags: html, css

We are designing a customizable height Widget with CSS, to use in our Backbone/Marionette app. We create the following estructure:

```
<!--WIdget Component (Layout View)-->
<div style="width:30%">
    <div id="Title" style="background-color: #0b64f9;color:#ffffff">Title Of the Widget</div>
    <div id="content" style="max-height: 250px;border:1px solid black;">
        <!--WIdget Content (ItemView distinct from Widget's Component)-->
            <div id="innerHead" style="background-color: coral;padding-left: 10px;padding-right: 10px;">
                   Inner Head

            </div>
            <div id="listado" style="overflow:auto;max-height:inherit;margin-bottom: 15px">
            <ul style="margin-top:0px">
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>
                <li>Content Of the Widgett</li>

            </ul>
         </div>
        <!-- end of widget Content-->
    </div>

</div>
<!-- end of widget Component-->
```

The inner Head div is messing up the structure. I need a way to do this that allow me to draw a scroll or not without setting any absolute's size in widget's content, making the content fits in the widget's container.

Notice that the current structure works ok when inner head ddiv oesn't exists. But I couldn't make it work when inner Head is present.

Can't use a position:fixed because the main page have also scroll.

UPDATE:

The best I have got is to make a empty div with the same height of  `#innerHead`, and insert into `#listado`. Example here http://jsfiddle.net/W6zz2/ . Any other solution more elegant?

Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer with an example jQuery Script to get the correct height.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, I'm trying to avoid using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Just give the `#listado`element a max height of 230px (`#content` height - `#innerhead` height), instead of `inherit`.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CS4NW/1/)

OR:

you could give `#content` an `overflow: hidden`

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CS4NW/2/)

UPDATE:

You could use this simple jQuery Script to adjust the `#listado` max-height depending on the height of the `#innerHead` element.

```
var contentHeight = $('#content').outerHeight();
var innerHeadHeight = $('#innerHead').outerHeight();
var maxHeight = contentHeight - innerHeadHeight;
$('#listado').css('max-height', maxHeight);
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YqQxd/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I explained, I can't use any absolute size (no px) inside of the widget's content. The idea is that  the content fits inside de size defined by the widget, whatever size.

Comment: Then use my second solution with `#content` `overflow:hidden`. There is no absolute size necessary.

Comment: Here is a fiddle with your inline styles and the added overflow declaration. http://jsfiddle.net/W6zz2/

Comment: Stil doesn't works. The scroll bar is partially hidden, and, if the innerhead Height is bigger, some content may not be visible. You can see the problem here (http://jsfiddle.net/YqQxd/)

Comment: Well if you also have a variable height of the innerhead, I am afraid there is no pure CSS solution, you would need a javascript that calculates the max-height of the #listado depending on the height of the #innerhead.